# SELECT from CTEs which might be null/undefined

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

Inside a function/stored procedure in Postgres 9.6 I want to grab data from two different tables using one CTE for each table like so:

```
WITH "CTE_from_table1" AS (SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1 WHERE id = $1),
     "CTE_from_table2" AS (SELECT column1, column2 FROM table2 WHERE id = $2)
SELECT 
  COALESCE(
     "CTE_from_table1".column1,
     "CTE_from_table2".column1,    
     CASE WHEN "CTE_from_table1".column2 = 42 OR "CTE_from_table2".column2 = 42 
          THEN 'Something is 42' ELSE 'something else!' END
   )
FROM "CTE_from_table1","CTE_from_table2";
```

(Data type of column1 and column2 are resp. identical for both tables: column1 being a text, column2 an integer.)

That works as long as both CTEs are defined. The problem is: The parameters `$1` and/or `$2` could be `null` or could contain IDs which are simply not there. In this case, I expect the result `something else!`, because the first two `COALESCE` parameters evaluate to `null` and the third, being the `CASE WHEN`, should go to its `ELSE` which would return `something else!`.

That's my theory. However, in practice I get `null` as soon as one of the CTEs is undefined/null. What can I do about that?

Comment: Can you join tables 1 and 2?

Comment: cross joining to a null dataset will generate a null data set.  So you need each table to always return at least one record.  You could union in a record for  col1,col2 with a special value and handle it in the case statement...with `CTE1 as (select column1, column2 from table1 where code < '00100' U NION ALL Select '-1',-1 )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the dreaded comma in the `FROM` clause.  Simple rule . . . *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  In this case, you want an "outer cross join".  The comma does an "inner cross join", so no rows are returned if either CTE has no rows.

Unfortunately, `OUTER CROSS JOIN` doesn't exist, so you can make do with `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
WITH "CTE_from_table1" AS (SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1 WHERE id = $1),
     "CTE_from_table2" AS (SELECT column1, column2 FROM table2 WHERE id = $2)
SELECT COALESCE(ct1.column1, ct2.column1,    
                CASE WHEN 42 IN (ct1.column2, ct2.column2)
                     THEN 'Something is 42'
                     ELSE 'something else!'
                END
               )
FROM "CTE_from_table1" ct1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     "CTE_from_table2" ct2
     ON 1=1;
```

I'm not a big fan of mixing `CASE` and `COALESCE()`, so I'd be inclined to write:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ct1.column1 IS NOT NULL THEN ct1.column1
             WHEN ct2.column1 IS NOT NULL THEN ct2.column1 
             WHEN 42 IN (ct1.column2, ct2.column2) THEN 'Something is 42'
             ELSE 'something else!'
        END)
```